# How to do patch update a model using ASP.net MVC, Entity Framework and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-5

I managed to create the basic CRUD operations using asp.net MVC

But I had a problem with regards to my field `Status`, `CreatedOn` and `CreatedBy`.

I want these fields to be populated during the Create Action and is not updated during the Edit Action but I don't want to use @HiddenFor for these fields because you can edit the DOM and still update these information before a POST request.

So basically what I want is to Patch Update my model with whatever data sent in the POST request. So I don't have to worry about the fields I don't want being modified are being changed in the Edit Action.

Here is my code for the model and action.

Model

```
[Table("Account")]
public class Account
{
    #region Properties

    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Account Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Time Offset")]
    [Range(-24,24)]
    public decimal TimeOffset { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class DbAccount : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action for Create

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Account account)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            account.Status = "ENABLED";
            account.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            account.CreatedBy = 1;
            db.Accounts.Add(account);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(account);
    }
```

Controller Action for Edit

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Account account)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            account.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
            account.ModifiedBy = 1;
            db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(account);
    }
```

How can I modify the model without affecting some specific properties specifically `CreatedOn` and `CreatedBy`, I want these properties to preserve their original value during Edit Action. I don't want to use Hidden Fields to store them. With my existing solution I used Hidden Fields but it can be modified in the DOM before POST request so it's not secure.

Comment: There's no such term as a "patch update".  What exactly are you trying to do?  You don't ask any question, nor do you suggest what is wrong or why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified` attaches the model to the context with all properties marked as modified. Try attaching it in the unchanged state instead and set the fields that are modifiable as modified.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Account account)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Accounts.Attach(account);

        db.Entry(account).Property(a => a.Name).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(account).Property(a => a.TimeOffset).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(account).Property(a => a.Status).IsModified = true;

        account.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        account.ModifiedBy = 1;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(account);
}
```